# ScrollView in FrameLayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-framelayout

I created a project with fragments, I can't insert a ScrollView with only an element inside (or two, it's the same). Infact I can see the scroll, but it doesn't come down. I don't want to add an layout_height in dp because it will cause inconsistencies with other devices (tablet etc)
Herewith enclosed you will find the xml code, 
Thank you in advance, 
Best regards

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/my_string"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution. The TextView filled in the entire layout, so the scrollView started from the top, considering the tabs and topBar. I added some "\n" and everything is working properly. 
Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: are you saying that if your `TextView` has bigger height than screen than also you are not able to scroll to bottom??

Comment: Exactly :/ I don't know what to do!

Comment: can you show us your device screenshot of this layout?

Comment: @VittoriaFrau see my answer.

Comment: I've tried with another string to show you my emulator but it seems that the problem is with my string. Should be possible that the problem is in "\n" in my string?

Comment: @himanshu1496 I've just updated my question

Answer (score 1):

try to remove **android:fillViewport="true"** this from your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have set its height to `match_parent` and remove `fillViewport`

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/my_string"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/my_string"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Basically I have changed the `android:layout_width` of `linearLayout`, try doing this and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but maybe I've just realized the problem, see my last update